# Excellent Rings Geometric Intuition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

A ring $R$ is called [***excellent***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring) if is quasi-excellent (so is a G-ring and a J-2 ring) and universally catenary.

Following two questions:

1) Wiki says that excellent ring "behave well with respect to the completion" $R \to \hat{R}$.

What does this mean concretely? Is there a wide class of properties properties P such that one have

"$R$ has property P $\Rightarrow \hat{R}$ has also property P"?

If yes, which properties P are meant? Which arguments can be done working with excellent rings? Or has "behave well with respect to the completion" another meaning?

2) Is there any geometric intuition (in sense of corresponding top space $Spec(R)$ behind excellent rings?

Comment: Basically all rings you ever encounter when doing algebraic geometry are excellent,for example all finite type schemes over a field or over a Dedekind domain. One example of a property $P$ is that of being reduced (excellent rings are analytically unramified). In some sense the class of excellent Noetherian schemes is the largest class of schemes for which resolution of singularities makes sense.

Comment: @user45878:Does there exist an intuition which class of properties $P$ in this case are "inherited by the completion" $R \to \hat{R}$ (or at least in local case: so $R_p$ has P then also $\hat{R_p}$?

I think that the goal of whole thery is that beeing complete is a really strong property so the aim is do arguments like:

Comment: -I want show property S for $R$ (or locally at all stalks $R_p$)

-is know that $R$ has property P, so $\hat{R}$ has property P

-the proof for S is for a complete ring $\hat{R}$ easier as for $R$, assume I showed that S holds for $\hat{R}$

-and under nice comditions I can pull property S (in some cases) back to $R$ (maybe in a weaker form)

Comment: Do you know a nice reference which might be contain an "overview" or like a catalogue :) of some basic ring properties which are preserved under completions for excellent rings?